# Is it possible to set custom backgroundColor in CNContactViewController?

Tags: swift, colors, background-color, uibackgroundcolor, cncontactviewcontroller

I'm trying to change `backgroundColor`, but I haven't been able to. This is my attempt:

```
let controller = CNContactViewController(for:  contact)
  
controller.view.backgroundColor = .orange

controller.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

However, it doesn't work. Is setting `backgroundColor` possible in `CNContactViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. CNContactViewController is out-of-process; it doesn't belong to you and you can't customize it.